# Can a Dell Poweredge R200 server be connected to HP D2600 Storageworks Disk Enclosure?

Tags: raid, storage, hp, dell-poweredge, hp-proliant

Can I setup a Dell Poweredge R200 server to use a HP D2600 Storageworks Disk enclosure by using a controller such as PERC 6e or the HP p412 / p410 (??) or other compatible controller in the Dell R200?

If it is possible, which controller would be recommended as I prefer the HP equipment (personal taste nothing against Dell) and as I received the Dell server for next to nothing (I actually swopped a harddrive and graphics card for it)

Can I plug the HP controller into the Dell PCI Expansion slot if this is possible?
Also the HP D2600 will be populated with SATA disks and specifically I will be wanting to use one of the following controllers with the D2600:

Smart Array P212/256 MB Controller; Smart Array P212/256 MB Controller with BBWC; Smart Array P411/256 MB Controller; Smart Array P411/512 MB Controller; Smart Array P411/512 MB Controller with BBWC; Smart Array P812

Any feedback would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the brand names to stop you connecting them together. If you have the right interfaces (external SAS for the D2600 isn't it?) then you'll be just fine. I've got Dell servers plugged into HP storage, HP Servers plugged into Dell storage, all kinds of other things talking to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine. You can connect to the enclosure with any of the HP controllers with external ports, or as another option, the LSI range of controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The D2600 isn't just a dumb disk box, for a start the actual disk layout and array configuration is written to each disk, you NEED to use one of HPs P-series controllers to setup the box using HPs ACU software that comes in HPs PSP driver pack. That said I'm not sure if the ACU will work on a non-HP server but there's only one way to find out.